# How can i manipulate an master table so i can add an calender to it when using splitview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, applet

So I am new to programming in swift and I am stuck. I am trying to add an calender to the left hand side by using splitview so that for each date I can save a sketch to it. How would I use the splitview function to write code for a calender? Or do I need to do it another way? Please view the picture below to get a better idea of it. All I need help with is if there is a way to manipulate splitview into using it more than just a table or is it another way to complete this project?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, so there's totally a way to do that. I'm just assuming you want to show a calendar for the current month.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
// If you wanted, you could easily change the 0 below to any number to get months in the future.
let targetDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 0, to: Date(), wrappingComponents: false)!
let targetMonth = calendar.component(.month, from: targetDate)
let targetYear = calendar.component(.year, from: targetDate)
var targetMonthComponents = DateComponents()
targetMonthComponents.year = targetYear
targetMonthComponents.month = targetMonth
let targetMonthDate = calendar.date(from: targetMonthComponents)!
let numberOfDays = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: targetMonthDate)!.count
```

Simply use a UITableViewDataSource to finish this.